# Вывести текст между тегами <h1> и </h1>

Tags: php, wordpress, simple-html-dom

Wordpress. Пытаюсь получить текст между тегами `<h1>` и `</h1>` (в случайных записях блога) и вывести его на Главной. Удалось получить текст между тегами `<h2>` и `</h2>` ([этот](https://pastebin.com/9qk2deNJ) код). Текст между тегами `<h1>` и `</h1>` функцией `get_the_content()` получить не удается, так как `<h1>` не находится в контенте (`echo get_the_content();` выводит содержимое статьи без `<h1></h1>`).
Каким образом можно достать h1, который находится вне контента?
[Здесь](https://pastebin.com/zgVxP9RA) содержимое single.php
Очевидно, что можно использовать `<?php echo get_the_title();?>` (как это используется в single.php), но это выводит не h1, а именно то название, которое указано в Записях (/wp-admin/edit.php) в стоблце "Заголовок". И этот "Заголовок" Отличается от настоящего h1.

В предыдущей моей записи ставится вопрос о том, как вывести содержимое h1, тогда как в этой записи вопрос состоит в другом: как получить заголовок h1, который находится вне контента.

Comment: Потому что его там нет. Это дополнительное поле

Comment: Или отдельный элемент таксономии(насколько помню так называется) вп

Comment: Посмотрите в теме где добавляется этот блок, и доставайте нужное допполе или куда он там сохраняется

Comment: Да. Надо посмотреть что это за доп поле. Посмотрите в файле function.php

Comment: Если он выводится где то. То посмотрите как он там выводится и будет вам счастье

Comment: Поищите в этих частях `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single-recipes' );` и `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'single' );`  этот код подцепляет шаблон если я правильно помню вп `template-parts/content-single.php`

Comment: И похорошему сделайте отдельный шаблон для вывода на главной случайных постов. Что бы потом в дальнейшем избежать подобной проблемы и просто посмотреть этот конкретный файл

Comment: А не так как у вас сейчас(я про ваши прошлые вопросы). Подцепляйте этот файл в цикле где идёт обход постов что вы выбрали wp_query

Comment: Не надо плодить вопросы. Надо дать полную информацию в предудущем вопросе.

Comment: @KAGGDesign это и есть его вопрос. По этой же самой теме

Comment: @Walfter и? данный вопрос надо закрывать как дубликат.

Comment: @KAGGDesign согласен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по коду, у вас там помимо title (поле заголовка записи, которое видно в админке) еще могут вытаскиваться дополнительные поля от ACF: dlitelnost и time_format. Вы можете при выводе всех записей запрашивать их доп.поля от ACF и склеивать нужный вам заголовок:

```
// ...

if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();

        /* Здесь нужно вывести h1 записи вместо заголовка записи */
        $h1 = get_the_title();
        if ( in_category($recipes_cat_id) || post_is_in_descendant_category($recipes_cat_id) ) : 
            $h1 .= ' ' . get_field('dlitelnost', get_the_ID());
            $h1 .= ' ' . get_field('time_format',  get_the_ID());
        endif;
        ?>

        <h1><?= esc_html( $h1 ); ?></h1>

        <?php
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Да, оказалось, что за вывод h1 отвечает advanced custom fields. Нашел как он выводится (get_field('custom_post_title')) и вывел его.